Как нажать клавишу Super в pyautogui
Хочу сделать так, чтобы код блокировал экран сочетанием клавиш Super + L.
Решил использовать библиотеку PyAutoGui, тк она не требует запуска с root. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу понять, как называется клавиша, которая отвечает за кнопку Super.
Пытался использовать следующие варианты: super, win, winLeft, command.
На один из вариантов не сработал. Что делать?
